# How to execute a C Program using fips libraries

Tags: c

I want to execute a C program named "dual_ec_drbg", generating random numbers.  The program is using fips libraries. I have fips libraries in a folder and I have installed a fips build.  But still I am unable to figure out how to add required header files in visual studio and get the output.  Once I try to execute it, I got the following errors:

```
Warning 1   warning C4627: '#include <stdlib.h>': skipped when looking for precompiled header use   c:\users\umar\desktop\th dev\drbgproj_2\drbgproj_2\drbgproj_2.cpp   56  1   DRBGProj_2
Warning 2   warning C4627: '#include <string.h>': skipped when looking for precompiled header use   c:\users\umar\desktop\th dev\drbgproj_2\drbgproj_2\drbgproj_2.cpp   57  1   DRBGProj_2
Warning 3   warning C4627: '#include <openssl/crypto.h>': skipped when looking for precompiled header use   c:\users\umar\desktop\th dev\drbgproj_2\drbgproj_2\drbgproj_2.cpp   58  1   DRBGProj_2
Warning 4   warning C4627: '#include <openssl/fips.h>': skipped when looking for precompiled header use c:\users\umar\desktop\th dev\drbgproj_2\drbgproj_2\drbgproj_2.cpp   59  1   DRBGProj_2
Warning 5   warning C4627: '#include <openssl/fips_rand.h>': skipped when looking for precompiled header use    c:\users\umar\desktop\th dev\drbgproj_2\drbgproj_2\drbgproj_2.cpp   60  1   DRBGProj_2
Warning 6   warning C4627: '#include <openssl/bn.h>': skipped when looking for precompiled header use   c:\users\umar\desktop\th dev\drbgproj_2\drbgproj_2\drbgproj_2.cpp   61  1   DRBGProj_2
Warning 7   warning C4627: '#include "fips_rand_lcl.h"': skipped when looking for precompiled header use    c:\users\umar\desktop\th dev\drbgproj_2\drbgproj_2\drbgproj_2.cpp   62  1   DRBGProj_2
Error   8   error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "StdAfx.h"' to your source?   c:\users\umar\desktop\th dev\drbgproj_2\drbgproj_2\drbgproj_2.cpp   543 1   DRBGProj_2
```

If any one has used any drbg of fips/nist, kindly guide me.

Comment: You could always try turning off pre-compiled headers in the visual studio settings.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but you may want to reconsider using Dual_EC_DRBG if you have a choice.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_EC_DRBG for an explanation.  AFAIK the threee other random number generators from NIST SP 800-90A are still considered to be secure.

Comment: infact i am doing some research on this drbg for which i have to test it against various parameters.